# Migrating Core Data Model from OSX to IOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsbundle

So I copied my xcdatamodeld (directory/package) to my IOS project. The

```
[NSBundle mainBundle] URLPathForResource:@"MyDataModelName" withExtension:@"momd"]
```

does not work.
I checked and the file is being copied as is with the extension .xcdatamodeld. So if I

```
[NSBundle mainBundle] URLPathForResource:@"MyDataModelName" withExtension:@"xcdatamodeld"]
```

It does return the file, but when I try to create the NSManagedObjectModel it does not work.

So I created a new project from xcode with core data and indeed the data model file in the project has an extension of xcdatamodeld, type -Core Data Model, but somehow it is being copied to the resource directory of the app as a .momd

So who is it being copied like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is weird... Instead of dragging the model from the osx to the ios project I dragged it from finder to the iOS project and it worked. When I added it the first time it did not recognized it as a core data model, although the xcode inspector panel said core data model. But the file was not in compile sources. I tried to add it manually and got an error that it did not have a way to process the file of type (null).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the safest / most reliable method of working with `.xcdatamodeld` files, is to use finder to move/copy from the source to your destination location, and then use the Xcode menu command "Add files to project..." to add the same file into your project structure.

Maybe this process is unnecessary, but for me it works every time.

Comment: This should always work... if/when it does not, check the path of the folder/group in which your CDM was added.  If you started a new project from scratch all folder/group paths should be correct, but if you have frankensteined together your project structure by copying lots of folders/files from other projects it's possible that some of your paths are wrong.  *** If you add an existing CDM into a wrong path, your project will not recognize it as a CDM package (and it will appear red in your compile build phase list)